mscorlib Error Occurs when Building Simulink Model using HDL Coder Workflow Advisor
I have a simple Simulink model that I want to build into FPGA code compatible with NI FPGA targets. I have installed the HDL Coder and the HDL Coder Support Package for NI FPGA Targets.
When I try running the HDL Workflow Advisor, I get the following error on step 1.2: Set Target Reference Design.

Failed Message: One or more errors occurred. Source: mscorlib HelpLink: None
Error using PostCallbacks.PostTargetReferenceDesignCallBack
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
HelpLink: None
Error in hdlturnkey.plugin.runCallbackPostTargetReferenceDesign
Error in hdlturnkey.ip.HDLTargetDriver/validateTargetReferenceDesign
Error in setTargetReferenceDesign
Error in Simulink.ModelAdvisor/executeCheckCallbackFct
Error in Simulink.ModelAdvisor/run
Error in Simulink.ModelAdvisor/runCheck
Error in ModelAdvisor.Node/runTaskAdvisor

Screenshot of error
This error occurs when building any model on this system. Strangely, I was able to build models using this workflow previously, although I'm not sure what changed since then. I know the error is occurring during .NET callbacks, but I don't know how to get any more debug info out of mscorlib or Simulink.
What I've tried:

Reinstalled HDL Coder and the Support Package for NI FPGA Targets
Ran Matlab as Admin
Tried with simple Blank DUT shipping example model

All cases result in the same error.

I figured out the problem. I had LabVIEW open for some other projects I was working on at the time. The HDL Coder Support Package needs LabVIEW to be closed so that it can programmatically control LabVIEW to script the LabVIEW FPGA implementation. After closing LabVIEW, I no longer get the error running task 1.2.
